# Fragment orientation handle AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have tried writing asynctask within fragment so that orientation dilemma can be solveable.So far asynctask working good but the progressbar which is associated with it, on screen change, not showing .
I have attached my code below .
On Screen rotate, progressbar and textview gets hidden

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_fragment, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    return view;
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void onViewClicked() {
    Log.w(TAG, "onBtn clicked");
    new URLAsyncTask().execute();

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressValue = savedInstanceState.getInt("value");
        System.out.println(progressValue);
        progressBar.setProgress(progressValue);
        String rcv = savedInstanceState.getString("value2");
        tvProgress.setText(rcv);

    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("value", progressBar.getProgress());
    outState.putString("value2", tvProgress.getText().toString());
}

private class URLAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String result = null;

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            SystemClock.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("Loading..... " + i);
            publishProgress(i);
        }

        result = "A dummy";

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        progressValue = values[0];
        tvProgress.setText("Loading .. at % ".concat(String.valueOf(progressValue)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute() : s : " + s);
        System.out.println(TAG + " " + progressValue);
        if (progressValue == 20) {
            tvProgress.setText("LOADING 100 % DONE");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

}
A bit help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand well your problem but I assume that you have problem with device orientation in fragment, that the AsynTask is reexecuting and displaying wrong percentage.
If I'm correct: Then instead using AsynTask, try this :

> [AsynTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

[image]
Also you can find some quality tutorial  on Udacity`s Android Developer Course,
(free) 
https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-networking--ud843